# Clojure async put! return value

Tags: clojure

[Clojure async put! docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async/put!) says (emphasis added)

> Asynchronously puts a val into port, calling fn0 (if supplied) when 
>   complete. nil values are not allowed. Will throw if closed. If 
>   on-caller? (default true) is true, and the put is immediately 
>   accepted, will call fn0 on calling thread.  **Returns nil.**

Yet the example code returns true

```
user=> (put! c "XYZ")
true
```

Are the docs incorrect or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/commit/cf8dc1bf207e646c14b2bf44763737fcb5f08c78), the new doc string reads:

```
"Asynchronously puts a val into port, calling fn1 (if supplied) when
complete, passing false iff port is already closed. nil values are
not allowed. If on-caller? (default true) is true, and the put is
immediately accepted, will call fn1 on calling thread.  Returns
true unless port is already closed."
```

Comment: Does `fn1` (the 1) mean one arg?

Comment: no, it's litterally the name of the argument `([port val fn1] (put! port val fn1 true))` *creative* eh?

Comment: I mean is the convention that fn1 means a 1 arg function? I tried `(put! c 125 (fn [] (println "done with put")))` and got `clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (1) passed` when doing a `take!`. But `(put! c 125 (fn [x] (println "done with put")))` worked fine, which leads me to believe that it wants a 1 arg function.

Comment: yes, thats right it's called with a single argument which is the result of the put. like this `(if on-caller?
           (fn1 ret)
           (dispatch/run #(fn1 ret)))`